# How exactly the bars(or rectangles) are created in d3 barChart demo part 1?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I understand every line of the [barchart source code](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7322386) . However, besides code on setting each `div`'s `width` using `.style("width", function(d) { return x(d) + "px"; })`, I don't see codes specifically saying  "let's make bars or rectangles".

```
var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, 420]);

d3.select(".chart")
  .selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("div")
    .style("width", function(d) { return x(d) + "px"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

My question:

Was the demo code a quick and dirty way of producing bars? Is there a formal or standard way of creating rectangles or bars using d3?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, those are not rectangles (as an SVG rectangle), but simply divs. Those divs have a rectangular shape and a background-color set in the CSS, so, they look like rectangles. Most of the D3 books (like Zhu's, Murray's etc) teach how to make charts with divs before moving to actual SVG rectangles.

But if what you don't understand is *how* these divs are created (judging by the title of your question), the code is right here:

```
d3.select(".chart")
    .selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("div");
```

What does it say? Let's see:

1. `.selectAll("div")`: This selects all the "div". But there is none so far... so, this is just a placeholder. Then:
2. `.data(data)`. This binds the data: the data is `data`. `data` is an array of 6 numbers. So, recapitulating, right now, there is no div, and these inexistent divs are bound to 6 numbers. So, our "enter" selection will be a selection of 6 divs, one for each number in the array.
3. `.enter()`: this is the "enter" selection. We have 6 numbers in our data, and zero div in the chart. So, our enter selection has 6 (new) divs.
4. `.append("div")`: This creates the divs. With `append`, we create the actual DOM elements.

This is a way to visually understand the enter selection:

[image]

In the first selectAll, we selected DOM elements that didn't exist at that time (they are just placeholders). Then, we bound data to those elements. Once we have 6 data numbers and 0 elements, our enter selection (corresponding to data without elements) has 6 new elements.

Comment: Thanks, your comment "Those divs have a rectangular shape and a background-color set in the CSS, so, they look like rectangles" helps.